# Rake: Processing files in a specified source directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

In my Rails project I have a specific list of externally-supplied files I want to process using Rake. My goal is to be able to specify the source directory of these files as an argument like so:

```
rake foofiles:process[vendor/sources]
```

Currently I'm specifying the file names (and their relative paths within the source directory) using a `FileList` assigned to a constant:

```
REQUIRED_FILES = FileList[
  'blah.csv',
  'subdir/something.csv',
  'subdir/monkeys/foo.bar',
  ...
]
```

How can I prepend each of these files with my source directory argument so that I can make a task that depends on those files existing in that directory? (ideally nothing would happen without *all* those files being present)

For example, if I used the `rake` command as typed above, I'd need my task to depend on `vendor/sources/blah.csv, vendor/sources/subdir/something.csv, vendor/sources/subdir/monkeys/foo.bar` etc.

**Edit:** Adding a prefix to each element in an array/list is relatively trivial, I'm more confused about how to structure my task(s) and their dependencies so I can actually access the source folder argument I've supplied, then use the new prepended file list as a dependency for the processing task that actually does the work.

The main invoked task is gonna have to look something like this if I want the syntax I used at the top:

```
namespace :foofiles do

  task :process, [:source_directory] => [???, my_newly_prepended_file_list] do |t, args|
    # Do stuff
  end

end
```

But I don't know how to provide the `:source_directory` argument to a task that does the prepending, and then subsequently return the prepended file list to the `:process` task as a dependency.

Comment: What do you mean by "I'd need my task to depend on vendor/sources/blah.csv, vendor/sources/subdir/something.csv, vendor/sources/subdir/monkeys/foo.bar etc"? You want those files to be passed in as an argument to your rake task, or are you talking about dependencies between rake tasks, or something different altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using an environment variable, it's much easier to work with in my case than Rake's built-in argument implementation. This way I can work with the variable and build my FileList with the prepended path (in the way Cameron suggested in the other answer) outside a task block:

```
namespace :foofiles do

  REQUIRED_FILES = [...]
  source_directory = ENV['SOURCEDIR'] || 'vendor/sources'

  source_files = FileList[REQUIRED_FILES.map { |relative_path| File.join source_directory, relative_path }]
  # Note: FileList can take an array inside the square brackets without needing the splat (*) operator

  task process: source_files do
    ...
  end

end
```

So now I can call it from the terminal like this:

```
SOURCEDIR=some/folder rake foofiles:process
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep an array of the suffixes, then append the argument to the start of each element in the array, then create the filelist?

```
suffixes = [
  'blah.csv',
  'subdir/something.csv',
  'subdir/monkeys/foo.bar',
]

files = suffixes.map { |suffix| File.join(prefix, suffix) }

file_list = FileList[*files]
```

Where `prefix` is the argument passed in.

Comment: I've edited my question. I'm more confused about the overall task/dependency structure as it relates to my case.